# Setup CI on Gitlab for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, gitlab, cirrus-ci

I'm trying to setup CI on Gitlab for Flutter Web. My `.
But it does not build the web app.

cirrus.yml` file:

```
image: cirrusci/flutter:latest

variables:
before_script:
  - flutter channel beta
  - flutter upgrade
  - flutter config --enable-web
  - flutter pub get
pages:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - flutter build web
    - cp -r build/web public
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - public
  only:
    - live
```

Pipeline doesn't start automatically. When I ran it manually, I'm getting following error:

```
No stages / jobs for this pipeline.
Specify variable values to be used in this run. The values specified in CI/CD settings will be used by default.
```

Comment: Could you add what your build output is so we can better diagnose what is going wrong? Thanks

Comment: Output is any web app that coded in Flutter.

Comment: Just to be sure: In GitLab your CI file has to have the file name `.gitlab-ci.yml` (because you wrote `cirrus.yml`, but maybe that's a typo). If this is the case: Does your pipeline start? What's the pipeline's output of the `deploy` stage?

Comment: I mean, when your build runs on gitlab, what do the logs say? (And yes please make sure your build actually runs when you push it, as meliade pointed out)

Comment: I just edited my question with my result of pipeline runner

Comment: How do i add variables in settings?